# $http.get & $http.post not working for MVC model but works with core php

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get and send data using `$http.get` & `$http.post`. However, it works only on core PHP(i.e if the link ends with .php).

I tried but could not get it done using MVC model of PHP.

For example take this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
            <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>
        </div>
        <p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
              $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
                .then(function(response) {
                  $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
              });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here as the link ends with .php the code works. But if you try to change the link to something which does not ends with an extension(.php, .htm) the code dosen't works despite of that file being a php one(but this time with MVC model of php)

Comment: Whats the other url you have tried, but didnt worked?

Comment: What you have tried. Are there any errors retrieving that data.

Comment: If you are not using any php framework like laravel, ci, zend then you must have to specify absolute file path with .php extension, since frameworks handle's the routing for you